# How to calculate age on a Microsoft Access form?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

On the Microsoft Access form I have created for patient data at a hospital I want to use the field DATE OF BIRTH and the field DATE OF FORM (current date) in order to calculate the three fields

- age(yr)
- age(mo), and
- age(days).

Is it possible to do this after just being given two dates?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. No, we're not going to do all the work for you. Do some research. Make some attempts. Come back with specific questions on specific problems.

Comment: @KevenDenen: I wish that were the case.  Unfortunately, too many people are willing to sell their souls for a couple of upvotes.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, those two dates are enough to calculate age. So you can use the DateDiff function in the Expression builder of the Age textboxes.

Below, I assume Age(yr) means age using years, Age(mo) means age using months, and Age(days) means age using days.

In the control source of Age(yr) textbox use:

```
=DateDiff("yyyy",[DateOfBirth],Date())
```

For Age(mo):

```
=DateDiff("m",[DateOfBirth],Date())
```

For Age(days):

```
=DateDiff("d",[DateOfBirth],Date())
```

Comment: This approach can produce incorrect results for the "Year" and "Month" values because the `DateDiff()` function does not behave they way you think it does. For `DateOfBirth=#2014-12-31#` and `DateToday=#2015-01-01#` the baby is only one day old but `DateDiff("yyyy",DateOfBirth,DateToday)` returns `1` (because the two dates are in different years).

Comment: Thanks Gord, you make a great point. Hence, the Age(days) DateDiff formula may be a more accurate age function if you divide the equation by 365. Our baby example would then be 0.065 and 0.063 years old respectively. Originally, I had the Age(mos) divided by 12 and Age(days) divided by 365 since we usually measure Age in years but KevenDenen had that edited out. I'm not sure of the rules of SO. I do wish the OP will respond to point us to his/her specific needs.

Comment: Feel free to edit those things back in if you think your understanding of the question is that they want the age in years for all three. I assumed that when they said they wanted age in days, they meant how many days old they were, not their age in years, calculated using their age in days. That's the problem with answering such a crappy question. The OP didn't post enough information to get a decent answer.